# Same name for functions in package and Global context

Tags: functions, packages, contexts, compatibility

I am using a package that was written for Mathematica 3 while I am now working on Mathematica 8. I have issues with 2 functions in particular, Order and GraphComplement. They are a part of this package but are also present in Mathematica 8 by default but with distinctly different arguments and working. (I am assuming they weren't around in Mathematica 3)

Now when I make use of some other functions in this package they make calls to both Order and GraphComplement and it keeps trying to use the in built wolfram version. I instead want it to use the one that comes with the package.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: How hard would it be to edit the package file and do a search and replace? (just curious how large a package it is)

Comment: Or basically overwrite all existing functions whenever an external one is imported with the same name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand the problem I think I can help, but what I propose is a bit weird.  I think you have a package that uses the unqualified Symbol name `Order` internally, and you need the package not to see the `` System`Order `` Symbol while it is defined.  To effect this you can temporarily change the [`Context`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Context.html) of `Order`, then put it back after loading the package.

As an example here is a bare-bones package defining a function `foo` that uses an internal definition for `Order`:

```
BeginPackage["MyStuff`"]

foo::usage = "my function";

Begin["`Private`"]

Order[args___] := {args} === Sort[{args}];

foo[a_, b_] := If[Order[a, b], "Arguments are in order", "Arguments are out of order"]

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

After saving this to `foo.m` if I call `Get[foo.m]` and try to use `foo` I have a problem:

```
Get["foo.m"]

foo[1, 2]
```

> SetDelayed::write: Tag Order in Order[args___] is Protected. >>
>
> ```
> If[1, "Arguments are in order", "Arguments are out of order"]
> ```

But if, after restarting the kernel, I first move `Order` out of the `System` context before loading the package:

```
Context[System`Order] = "hold`";

Get["foo.m"]

Context[hold`Order] = "System`";
```

I can now call my `foo` as intended:

```
foo[1, 2]
foo[4, 2]
```

> ```
> "Arguments are in order"
>
> "Arguments are out of order"
> ```

This works because while the package is being defined `Order` is not found in the context path, and a new Symbol `` MyStuff`Private`Order `` is created and defined instead:

```
Definition[foo]
```

> ```
> foo[MyStuff`Private`a_, MyStuff`Private`b_] := 
>  If[MyStuff`Private`Order[MyStuff`Private`a, MyStuff`Private`b],
>    "Arguments are in order",
>    "Arguments are out of order"]
> ```

And [`Order`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Order.html) still works elsewhere as its context is restored:

```
Order["a", "b"]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

Comment: This is... exactly what I was looking for. It seems to work flawlessly for Order however when I try to do this for GraphComplement I get this:

System`GraphComplement::shdw: Symbol GraphComplement appears in multiple contexts {System`,GrafPack`Basics`}; definitions in context System` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions. >>

Any idea what went wrong here?

Comment: Just checked. The warning is there but it seems to work fine anyway. Much thanks my friend. Accepted. :)

Comment: @jasonheush12 Thanks for the Accept.  Don't hesitate to remove it if you find this fails.  Your warning is probably caused by a background (re)load of `GraphComplement`.  Try using that `System` function in some trivial application before changing its context and loading your package, and see if the message goes away.  (Incidentally I ran into these background load consequences myself [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5649379).)

Comment: +1, Nice use of this change-symbol-context capability. However,  I personally still view this as a hack (although probably the best one can do). The real way out would be to implement an alternative loader (`Get` / `Needs`) with a read stage (access to code in box form, and then fully parsed but not yet evaluated, using hooks to inject user-defined operations). In this way, we might for example get a code in held form, already parsed, and then simply replace all ``System`Order`` symbols to ``MyPackage`Order``.

Comment: @Leonid That sounds like a more robust approach, but I'm far too lazy. :^)  Oh, and thank you.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The real problem is, this (new loader) can't be successful as a small stand-alone piece. It has to come together with a new package / module system, that would be 1. Compatible with the existing one 2. Extensible and having more possibilities. I did some work on such things, and a few experiments, but didn't have the time to make something robust and self-contained. I plan to return to this topic at some point, there are several reasons why such thing can be very useful (another one would be real read time and a possibility for Lisp - style macros).