# Cannot set DownValues to ValueList while loading package

Tags: warning-messages, packages, physics, initialization, downvalues

> I have installed a package named [HEP](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4580/#downloads) from Wolfram Library Archive which contains several `.m` files by `Files -> Install` (Install for this user only) and by loading it in a notebook by `` <<Package` ``.
>
> One of the them is `Spinor.m` which when loaded gives the following error message saying `Cannot set DownValues to ValueList`

[image: Problem loading Spinor.m package]

I have not encountered such a problem of this kind before and couldn't find any documentation regarding this issue.

> Another problem occurs while loading the `StandardModel.m` package in a similar way resulting the error message

[image: TagSet and TagSetDelayed error]

I would request to download the `Spinor.m` package from the [Wolfram Library Archive](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4580/#downloads) and try it out in your own Mathematica as I am not sure whether the problem is with my machine (using `Mathematica 11.0`) or not. Any solution or guidance regarding the first problem is highly encouraged to resolve this problem. THANKS for all valuable suggestions in advance !

Answer (score 2):

That is an ancient package (revision date 1991-07-01) and it is unsurprising there are incompatibilities.  Specifically the package seems to be making definitions in a strange way with an undocumented function `ValueList` in e.g.

```
If[$VersionNumber > 1.9, DownValues[AbsSquared1] = ValueList @@ AbsSquared1Rules, 
 DownValue[AbsSquared1] = ValueList @@ AbsSquared1Rules]
```

As a *first attempt* at fixing this you might try loading the package with:

```
Block[{System`ValueList = List},
  Get["Spinor.m"]
]
```

However I expect you will run into other problems while attempting to make this package work.

Comment: The error message is suppressed but the problem remains whenever anything related to `Spinor.m` is encountered. @Mr.Wizard

Comment: @Rohan As I said I am not surprised; the package may require a complete rewrite for contemporary versions of *Mathematica*.  Among many other things `NonCommutativeMultiply` is now a built-in function and not necessarily compatible with the package Symbol of the same name; you may need [context manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103551/121) to get around this.  Honestly if you can find an alternative to using this package I recommend you do so, as it may be a lot of work for you otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the Advice @Mr.Wizard. In addition, can you name any such packages for Mathematica other than `FeynArts` or `FeynCalc` for High Energy Physics for calculating Cross Sections and other relevant details?

Comment: @Rohan Unfortunately I cannot; that topic is well outside my realm of knowledge.

Comment: @Rohan As far as diagram generators are concerned, there are no other Mathematica packages than FeynArts. Many people also use QGRAF, but this Fortran code lacks a GUI or even a diagram plotter and is more 
difficult to use than FeynArts. As for FeynCalc-like packages, have a look at HEPMath (hepmath.hepforge.org) and 
Package-X (packagex.hepforge.org). AFAIK HEPMath is not actively developed anymore, but the last release was not so long time ago, so it should still work with the recent Mathematica versions. Package-X is still actively developed, but it has no interface to FeynArts.

Comment: Finally you might also be interested in FormCalc (www.feynarts.de/formcalc), which is much faster than the above-mentioned packages (and FeynCalc), but is less flexible.