# How can I reassign `I`

Tags: input

Is there any way I can have `I` not refer to the imaginary unit?

I like the letter `I`, it's a terrible choice of letter for the imaginary unit, and I almost never input `I` directly anyway.

I would have thought there would be a way of shadowing any function I don't want to address within a particular scope, and have that scope be the one used by my notebook. But I can't figure out how to do that.

The docs for `Locked` do **not** explain this.

Comment: `I` has the [`Locked`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Locked.html) attribute and thus cannot be modified.

Comment: @JHM There must be some workaround though... surely...

Comment: There isn't. It's ["bulletproof"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/PackageBulletproofing.html). I recommend that you read the documentation on [`Locked`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Locked.html).

Comment: When I was a beginner of Mathematica, I disliked `I` being a system symbol since my variables and function names in applications were best called `I`.  A "trick" around this is to use Greek capital iota (alias: `esc`-`I`-`esc`), which looks exactly like the Latin `I`.  With more experience, I trained myself to have all my variables begin with lower case letter (since the capital ones are *always* reserved for system variables anyway).

Comment: When you write code in _Mathematica_, it is a good practice to use lowerCamelCase to avoid conflicts with the built-in functions.

Comment: @JHM Put it this way, if I can override it inside a `Module[]` tag, why can't I make it so the interpreter is similarly scoped?

Comment: Module renames the variable.  Try `Module[{I}, I]`.

Comment: `Module` renames the symbol. i.e. `Module[{I}, SymbolName[I]]`. Observe that the `Block` version of that code does not work because `Block` does not rename variables.

Comment: `I` is a terrible choice of letter for a variable name (but reasonable for a system-level constant)... I'm so glad that they locked it down.

Comment: @QuantumDot but sometimes you want to use the same letters as the thing you're working on, "best practice" be damned. That's why it has the whole greek letter thing in the first place, right? If I was using some other programming language, I'd use words, but large part of the appeal is being able to use the symbols you want (except I and N)

Comment: If you _really_ want `I`, try `\[CapitalIota]` (input as `Esc I Esc`). Likewise, `\[CapitalNu]` for `N`

Comment: @R.M. I'd rather have to write `I = ImaginaryUnit[]` - or even better `Import[Imaginary]` or something - imagine someone at Wolfram Research realised that global variables are always a terrible idea.

Comment: Not to mention, `C`, `D`, `E`, and `O` are built-in as well.

Comment: @JHM arggggggggg... yes. I want to rename them all!

Comment: Perhaps you might consider writing yourself a pair of transpilers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler With the tap of a key the text in your word processor would be translated from your desired form into Mathematica's required form, sent to Mathematica, the code runs and the resulting notebook is translated back to precisely your desired form. That will let you use every name exactly the way you want.

Comment: `\[ScriptCapitalI]` uses a style variant of I

Comment: @Bill I can't say that I hadn't already seriously contemplated that option. I was hoping there was an easier solution, by just to scoping the notebook differently.

Comment: With modern languages it is much easier to write small translators than it used to be. If you did a very good job of that so that other people could understand it, easily modify it and enhance it then you might get yourself an excellent reputation from that project.

Comment: @Bill I'm not sure I want a reputation for doing that kind of thing ;)

Comment: A reputation for producing a very high quality tool that allows you and others to easily solve a problem that would otherwise be difficult to solve would not be a bad reputation to have. Yes, some might not want to use that tool to change the case of predefined variables, but a tool that would easily and predictably allow other kinds of transformations might gain some respect. Imagine, for example, being able to easily overcome the "challenges" associated with use of subscripted variables that so many users seem compelled to use.

Comment: @Bill yes, the subscripts, they suck too. It would be nice to do things like $x = \{x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3\}$. A lot is just about readability. But, I don't want to spend my time working on that kind of thing, and I definitely don't want to give people the impression that I enjoy it.

Comment: Lucas, I changed to designation on this question from *closed* to *already has an answer*.  Please see the link inserted at the top of your post.  I hope that you find my answer there of some use.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, I really didn't understand the reason given before (I did understand why some people didn't *like* it). This `$PreRead` and `$PostRead` system is interesting.