# Efficiency of the rule _ * 0 := 0

Tags: evaluation, upvalues

In the standard evaluation process, innermost parts are evaluated first. For example:

```
In[0]:= (a/a + 1) * 0
```

The evaluation process gives:

```
(a/a + 1) * 0 = (1 + 1) * 0 = 2 * 0 = 0
```

In that case, this evaluation doesn't make sense because the result will always be 0.
I'd like to write a rule where the left member "x" is never evaluated:

```
Multiply[x_, 0] := 0
```

For example:

```
In[1]:= Multiply[Simplify[D[Cos[x]^(x + 1)/x^4, {x, 5}], 0]
Out[1]:= 0
```

without evaluating Simplify[D[Cos[x]^(x + 1)/x^4, {x, 5}] which is time consuming.

The built-in rule of Mathematica is very slow too (about 2s on my machine), so it means innermost parts are evaluated first:

```
In[2]:= 0 * Simplify[D[Cos[x]^(x + 1)/x^4, {x, 5}]]
Out[2]:= 0
```

I'm not sure this kind of concept exists in Mathematica. Any suggestions?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The reason it's defined this way is so that `(1/(1-1))*0` properly gives an error message.

Answer (score 6):

We can use the attribute `HoldAll`:

```
SetAttributes[Multiply, HoldAll]

Multiply[___, 0, ___] = 0;
Multiply[args___] := Times[args]

Multiply[Pause[1000], 0] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {4.*10^-6, 0}
> ```

Comment: Funny, I read this as wanting to modify the behavior of `Times`, but reading it again that may not have been the intent at all. +1  I think you have an error though, with `HoldFirst`.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.  I don't have time today to address this in depth but this kind of evaluation can be controlled by attributes, specifically [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html).  One *cannot* change the attributes of core functions without risking *serious* problems however, but just to illustrate:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Times},
  SetAttributes[Times, HoldAll];
  0*Simplify[D[Cos[x]^(x + 1)/x^4, {x, 5}]]
]
```

This is basically like using `Unevaluated` (below) but it does not require foreknowledge of which part to apply it to.

```
0*Unevaluated[Simplify[D[Cos[x]^(x + 1)/x^4, {x, 5}]]]
```

Comment: Thank you for these answers.<br/>But how to override the `Times` function globally for all my computations (not locally with InheritedBlock) without risking problems?

Comment: @BP75 I don't believe you can as modifying a deeply integrated System function could have many unforeseen consequences.  The best I can offer would be an automatic replacement of all `Times` expressions *in user input* with a separate function like Chip Hurst's `Multiply`, but I don't know what your actual application is and this may not help.  See: [(117)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117/121), [(7223)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7223/121), [(16652)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16652/121), [(63147)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63147/121)