# How to abbreviate context names?

Tags: packages, contexts

It's convenient to abbreviate often-used function names, eg `Dim = Dimension`.

Is it possible to abbreviate long context symbols, e.g. *Combinatorica* when the context is not inserted in the context path, like with

```
Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs["Combinatorica`"]]
```

`Com = Combinatorica` doesn't work, eg: `` Com`Star[6] `` is fixed by the interpreter. Is there a way to abbreviate it?

Comment: One of the actual strengths of the Mathematica language design is that it uses spelled-out, meaningful names rather than verbose but possibly cryptic names.

Comment: @murray, I aint got time for that

Comment: My long experience with such things, going back to APL, is that it takes more time to recall the correct terse, cryptic abbreviation than to type a longer but descriptive name. Of course this is predicated upon good touch-typing skills.

Comment: In exploratory data analysis there's much testing of properties of data structures that is then deleted, so not only do I abbreviate, eg, Dimension, but I use lower case 'dim' because speed is of the essence. What do you think of that?

Comment: @alancalvitti Are you aware of the Cmd-K shortcut (on a mac) to autocomplete? So `Dim Cmd-K` will give you `Dimension`

Comment: They had to make it a 2-hand shortcut ah?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am not sure these are the best ways but they should work.
You could do what you did with `Dimensions` for all the symbols in `` Combinatorica` ``

For example, running this

```
replaceAndLoad[context_String -> toContext_String] := 
 Block[{$ContextPath},
  Needs[context];
  Scan[ToExpression[
     toContext <> StringReplace[#, context ~~ sym__ :> sym] <> 
      "=" <> #] &, Names[context <> "*"]]
  ]
```

Now, do

```
replaceAndLoad["Combinatorica`" -> "Com`"]
```

You could also overload `MakeExpression` to change Com to Combinatorica at the parsing stage... But I would probably do something different and basic, like an `InputAlias` or `InputAutoReplacement`. With these you could even replace them with a framed box in a special color that means "context combinatorica", or a tooltip, or simply an `Interpretation` that writes `` Com`stuff `` but is interpreted as `` Combinatorica` ``...

Answer (score 10):

This question is not too distantly related to my own on StackOverflow:

[Exposing Symbols to $ContextPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7912984/618728)

Leonid provides an interesting approach there that could be adapted to your problem.

Rojo provides a solution that creates "proxy symbols" but these are not 100% equivalent.  `Information` no longer works correctly for example:

```
?? Com`KSubsets
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This only gives the name of the Symbol it points to an not the usage message or the definition.

I prefer using `$PreRead` for situations like this (e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1123/121)).  Although it only works interactively it has the advantage of using the *actual* symbols rather than proxies, so all the functions like `Unprotect`, `Information`, etc. work correctly.

```
Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs["Combinatorica`"]]

$PreRead = # /. 
    name_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "Com`*"] &) :> 
     With[{nn = StringReplace[name, "Com`" -> "Combinatorica`"]}, 
      nn /; NameQ[nn]] &;
```

Now `Information` et al work correctly:

```
?? Com`KSubsets
```

Comment: Very nice Mr.Wizard - maybe I should have waited to accept. I  had no time to test these issues

Comment: @alancalvitti as you may know you can always change the Accept later, but it is probably a good idea to wait a bit longer before placing it.  Also I'm not claiming that this method is superior and I was specifically looking for an alternative to it when I posted the SO question referenced.  Nevertheless I find it to have the best characteristics when it is applicable.

Comment: Just when I thought I finally got a grip on Mma you made me aware that it was just an illusion. :-(

Comment: @ndroock1 I have the same feeling sometimes.  I'm curious though, what specifically makes you say that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - I think it was $PreRead that triggered the thought.

Comment: @ndroock1, feel free to unaccept and take all my badges away from me, hehe. +1, the main loop didn't come to mind

Comment: @alancalvitti,  
Remember that there's only one $PreRead across the kernel, so if you want to add another context abbreviation or use it in any other way at the same time, you have to be careful

Comment: Ok interesting. Subtle issues.

Comment: @alancalvitti Rojo's caveat is valid but know that it is possible to have numerous replacement rules in `$PreRead` (`# /. {rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4} &`) so long as they do not internally conflict.  If you get fancy you may need `//.` so that all rules are applied to a particular expression, since otherwise only the first that matches is.  Be aware that `$PreRead` operates on the Box form of input and must return valid Box form as I noted in the comments [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1123/121).

Comment: @Rojo I know you were joking but FYI the Enlightened badge is yours to keep no matter what happens to the Accept.